# curl to return http code, time response and extract a json value

Tags: json, shell, curl, sh, jq

I'm studying about shell script and I got stuck into a problem.

I have to monitor a API URL that returns to me a response in JSON format. Here's a example of this response:

```
         {
                "Result": 0,
                "ExecutionTime": 0,
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "item1": "x",
                        "item2": x,
                        "item3": x,
                        "item4": x,
                        "genre1": x,
                        "genre2": x,
                        "item5": x,
                        "item6": x,
                        "desc": {
                            "por": {
                                "name": "santa-claus",
                                "item7": "xxxx",
        }
        }
}
        ]
    }
```

The problem is that I need that the curl command returns to me three params: 1. the "name" (which is in the json response), 2. the http code and 3. the time response. For example, I expect something like this:

```
santa-claus    #from json extract
200            #http code
347ms          #time response
```

I'm using shell script, and what I have now is this curl command:

```
curl -X "GET" -w "%{http_code}\n" "https://my-api-url-here&compress=true" | jq -r '.Items[] | .descs.por.name'`
```

This is returning to me this error:

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "Items"
santa-claus
```

The "jq" part is correct, if I do this curl without "-w "%{http_code}\n"", everything is ok. But I need that three responses, as I said...
about time response, I read something about "%{time_starttransfer}", but I don't know how to apply this in my curl command...

Is that a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have `curl` output a custom JSON object which `jq` can then parse as well. (The values `http_code` and `time_total` take should be safe for this kind of interpolation.)

```
curl -X "GET" -w '{"code": "%{http_code}", "time": "%{time_total}"}' "https://my-api-url-here&compress=true" |
  jq -sr '.[0].Items[] | .descs.por.name, .[1].code, .[1].time'
```

The block output by `-w` will follow the body of the request as a separate object. The `-s` option reads both objects into a single array, which your filter than then index as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!! I understand it! Tried to do this here and it's almost there, but I got this now:
"

santa-claus
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index object with number
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index object with number
"
there's something wrong in "code" and "time" responses, I've saw that in this format that you made, these two options are like in the same json as the url json response, in the end of line

Comment: Probably need `'(.[0].Items[] | .descs.por.name), .[1].name, .[1].time'`, as I think `|` has lower prority than `,`.